# What is the difference between a linear independent set and a generating set?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

im having difficulty because onto have columns of generating set and one to one has columns of linear independence but the way we prove whether a standard matrix has linear independent columns are generating columns are the same.

Comment: $\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0)\}$ is a linearly independent set. However, you can't get $(0,0,1)$ from linear combinations of such a set. To be a generating set (of $\mathbb{R}^3$) it must have three linear independent vectors. The same happens in higher dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

A linearly independent set of vectors is a set of vectors such that none can be written as a non-trivial linear combination of the others, whereas a generating set may have linearly dependent vectors in it, but it has the property that the span (all linear combinations of vectors) makes up the entire space.